# Java SOAP 1.5 XML construction issues

Tags: java, xml, soap, soap-client

I am developing a Java SOAP 1.5 client application which communicates with a SOAP server endpoint.

However, the constructed XML request is not what I expect, and it is returning a fault response from the server.

Here is part of my code which constructs the XML envelope :

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPFactory soapFactory       = SOAPFactory.newInstance();

SOAPMessage soapMessage       = messageFactory.createMessage();

SOAPPart soapPart             = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

// SOAP Envelope
SOAPEnvelope envelope         = soapPart.getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header             = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader(); 

envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("cs", "urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/");
```

Now compare this to the request that is actually being sent :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:cs="urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <cs:chargeBoxIdentity>Test</cs:chargeBoxIdentity>
        <wsa:Action>/ChangeConfiguration</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>Fake OCPP571322528896</wsa:MessageID>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <cs:changeConfigurationRequest>
            <cs:key>LaMa_ConnectionRate</cs:key>
            <cs:value>5120</cs:value>
        </cs:changeConfigurationRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

See how `xmlns:SOAP-ENV` is actually different to what is intended. I don't know why this is. This can be part of the problem. Also, is it possible to strip the declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` from the request , as it could be an issue also.

Comment: Put the URL from your code of the SOAP-ENV into a browse and look at the actual webpage for the namespace.  The header is being changed because the webpage schema is being used.  You may want to update the wsa to latest 2006 version instead of 2005.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your reply. I was looking at this. How can I solve this so that it doesn't change? I have a separate Python application which sends the same request, without the declaration and has the correct SOAP-ENV, and this works fine.

Comment: What is the cs namespace using?  It may be overriding the newer namespace.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean?

Comment: You have 3 schema and the may be using different versions of the same namespace.  The last names in your Envelope will override attributes in the first two.

Comment: @jdweng I tried modifying wsa to 2006, but still no joy. Do you know how I could strip the declaration "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>" from the request. This may be what is causing the issue, but not sure. The Python script doesn't send this in the request and works fine. Thanks